# use batch file to insert string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to use batch file to insert a string to replace the empty space in particular column 
say i have a **input.txt** like following

```
field1      field2           field3
AAAAA       BBBBB            CCCCC
DDDDD                        EEEEE
FFFFF                        
GGGGG       HHHHH
```

I need to insert a string "NULL" on each field that is empty and for sure that field 1 is not empty and **field 2,3** sometime will be empty. In addition, space between field1 &field2 is different from field2 & field 3

**output.txt**

```
field1      field2           field3
AAAAA       BBBBB            CCCCC
DDDDD       NULL             EEEEE
FFFFF       NULL             NULL    
GGGGG       HHHHH            NULL
```

Because i am still need to batch file scripting.. 
i try the to write the code (field 2 is always start from 12 character from left and field 3 is always 29 character from left)

```
@echo off

set line= 
for /F in (input.txt)do
if "!line:~12" equ " " 
write "NULL"   >> (i am not sure whether this work)

if "!line:~29" equ " "
write "NULL"  

echo .>> output.txt
```

Perhaps, anyone could correct my mistake?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, here is a solution in Python.  This program will work just fine with either Python 3.x or with Python 2.7.  If you are very new to programming, I suggest Python 3.x, because I think it is easier to learn.  You can get Python for free from here:  http://python.org/download/

The latest version of Python is version 3.2.3; I suggest you get that.

Save the Python code in a file called `add_null.py` and run it with the command:

```
python add_null.py input_file.txt output_file.txt
```

The code, with lots of comments:

```
# import brings in "modules" which contain extra code we can use.
# The "sys" module has useful system stuff, including the way we can get
# command-line arguments.
import sys

# sys.argv is an array of command-line arguments.  We expect 3 arguments:
# the name of this program (which we don't care about), the input file
# name, and the output file name.
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    # If we didn't get the right number of arguments, print a message and exit.
    print("Usage: python add_null.py <input_file> <output_file>")
    sys.exit(1)

# Unpack the arguments into variables.  Use '_' for any argument we don't
# care about.
_, input_file, output_file = sys.argv


# Define a function we will use later.  It takes two arguments, a string
# and a width.
def s_padded(s, width):
    if len(s) >= width:
        # if it is already wide enough, return it unchanged
        return s
    # Not wide enough!  Figure out how many spaces we need to pad it.
    len_padding = width - len(s)
    # Return string with spaces appended.  Use the Python "string repetition"
    # feature to repeat a single space, len_padding times.
    return s + ' ' * len_padding


# These are the column numbers we will use for splitting, plus a width.
# Numbers put together like this, in parentheses and separated by commas,
# are called "tuples" in Python.  These tuples are: (low, high, width)
# The low and high numbers will be used for ranges, where we do use the
# low number but we stop just before the high number.  So the first pair
# will get column 0 through column 11, but will not actually get column 12.
# We use 999 to mean "the end of the line"; if the line is too short, it will
# not be an error.  In Python "slicing", if the full slice can't be done, you
# just get however much can be done.
#
# If you want to cut off the end of lines that are too long, change 999 to
# the maximum length you want the line ever to have.  Longer than
# that will be chopped short by the "slicing".
#
# So, this tells the program where the start and end of each column is, and
# the expected width of the column.  For the last column, the width is 0,
# so if the last column is a bit short no padding will be added.  If you want
# to make sure that the lines are all exactly the same length, change the
# 0 to the width you want for the last column.
columns = [ (0, 12, 12), (12, 29, 17), (29, 999, 0) ]
num_columns = len(columns)

# Open input and output files in text mode.
# Use a "with" statement, which will close the files when we are done.
with open(input_file, "rt") as in_f, open(output_file, "wt") as out_f:
    # read the first line that has the field headings
    line = in_f.readline()
    # write that line to the output, unchanged
    out_f.write(line)

    # now handle each input line from input file, one at a time
    for line in in_f:
        # strip off only the line ending
        line = line.rstrip('\n')

        # start with an empty output line string, and append to it
        output_line = ''
        # handle each column in turn
        for i in range(num_columns):
            # unpack the tuple into convenient variables
            low, high, width = columns[i]
            # use "slicing" to get the columns we want
            field = line[low:high]
            # Strip removes spaces and tabs; check to see if anything is left.
            if not field.strip():
                # Nothing was left after spaces removed, so put "NULL".
                field = "NULL"

            # Append field to output_line.  field is either the original
            # field, unchanged, or else it is a "NULL".  Either way,
            # append it.  Make sure it is the right width.
            output_line += s_padded(field, width)

        # Add a line ending to the output line.
        output_line += "\n"
        # Write the output line to the output file.
        out_f.write(output_line)
```

Output from running this program:

```
field1      field2           field3
AAAAA       BBBBB            CCCCC
DDDDD       NULL             EEEEE
FFFFF       NULL             NULL
GGGGG       HHHHH            NULL
```

Comment: I'm glad it is working for you!  :-)  Python is much easier than the Microsoft "batch" language, so this is better for the future, too.

Comment: hi Stevaha, yup i will try to pick up this language as well!!Usually my work involve in batch file scripting so i need to call the python file in a cmd batch file. how do you call in batch file?
if not how do you automate it?
If the scenario it read a folder, for each file with .txt format 
addnull.py <input> <output>, i try to google it but not quite understand yet..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think what you wanted to do was possible in Microsoft "batch" scripting.  But there is a full set of string operators documented here:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

But batch files are horrible and I hope you can use something better.  If you want a Python solution, or AWK, I could help you.

If I were you, and I was really going to do this in "batch" scripting, I would break each line up into three substrings, using the `~x,y` column slicing (where `x` is the first column and `y` is the second).  Then check to see if each one is just spaces, and for the ones that are just spaces, replace with "NULL".  Then rejoin the substrings back into one string, and print that.  Do this inside a loop and you have your program.

Comment: Hi Stevaha, Thanks for the suggestion.. I not very familiar with Python, if using python can it be run as a schedule task in window? Actually i also thinking using vbscript, yet due to i new to coding.. any suggestion i am welcome!!! hope you can assist me on this..

Comment: I don't know VBScript but there will be other people here on StackOverflow who do know it.  Python does not come standard with Windows, so you would have to install it.  If VBScript is more standard at your work, you might want to use that.  But if you did install Python, then sure you could run it as a scheduled task.

Comment: Hi Stevaha, 
Thanks, i would give it a try to install python first.. and explore new coding method..
Would you show me how to use python to deploy this task? 
An explanation of how your code work is appreciated as i not familiar with python... :)